# Outputting nested array, outputs key and not content?

Tags: javascript

After reading this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json) I am still having issues looping over my data structure:

```
users:
 {
   'names': ['john','chris'],
   'addresses': ['10 king street', '20 king street'],
 }
```

The loop:

```
for (const prop in this.payload) {
      console.log(prop); //names

      for (const item of prop) {
           console.log(item); //n //a //m //e //s
      }
 }
```

It appears to be outputting the letters of the key "names", then doing the same for the other keys.

Why? The expected output is:

```
names
john
chris
addresses
10 king street
20 king street
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`prop` is a string. If you loop over a string, you will loop over its characters, and that is what you're seeing.

Instead, obtain the value referred to by that property name, and loop over that value:

```js
this.payload = {
  'names': ['john', 'chris'],
  'addresses': ['10 king street', '20 king street'],
};

for (const prop in this.payload) {
  console.log(prop); //names

  for (const item of this.payload[prop]) {
    console.log(item);
  }
}
```

Better yet, make use of `Object.entries()`:

```js
this.payload =  {
   'names': ['john','chris'],
   'addresses': ['10 king street', '20 king street'],
};

for (const [prop, items] of Object.entries(this.payload)) {
    console.log(prop);
    
    for (const item of items) {
        console.log(item);
    }
}
```

Or you could use `Object.values()` if you don't care about the property names.

Comment: Thanks. With object.values I get "items is not iterable"

Comment: @panthro With `Object.values` you would need to change the first `for` to `for (const values of Object.values(this.payload))`

Comment: Thanks, why use values over entries? And why use these over for loops?

Comment: @panthro _" 
Thanks, why use values over entries?"_ Use `.values` if you only care about the values and not the property names ("names", "addresses"). Use `.entries` if you want the values and the property names. _"And why use these over for loops?"_ These are `for` loops.

Answer (score 0):

To access the values, use `this.payload[prop]`

```
for (const prop in this.payload) {
  console.log(prop); //names

  for (const item of this.payload[prop]) {
       console.log(item);
  }
 }
```